# Conditionally include file during publish to Azure WebJob

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2022, azure-webjobs

I have a webjob on Azure that I want to conditionally include the "settings.job" file based on the build configuration in Visual Studio 2022. My current pubxml file is as follows:

```
<Project>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <WebPublishMethod>MSDeploy</WebPublishMethod>
        <PublishProvider>AzureWebSite</PublishProvider>
        <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Nightly</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
        <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
        <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>https://myfakeapp.azurewebsites.net</SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>
        <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>false</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
        <ResourceId>my/fake/resourceid</ResourceId>
        <UserName>$myfakeusername</UserName>
        <_SavePWD>false</_SavePWD>
        <ExcludeApp_Data>false</ExcludeApp_Data>
        <MSDeployServiceURL>myfakeapp.scm.azurewebsites.net:443</MSDeployServiceURL>
        <MSDeployPublishMethod>WMSVC</MSDeployPublishMethod>
        <SkipExtraFilesOnServer>true</SkipExtraFilesOnServer>
        <EnableMsDeployAppOffline>true</EnableMsDeployAppOffline>
        <EnableMSDeployBackup>true</EnableMSDeployBackup>
        <DeployIisAppPath>myfakeapp</DeployIisAppPath>
        <WebJobType>Triggered</WebJobType>
        <WebJobName>MyFakeApp_Nightly_Job</WebJobName>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Target Name="CopyFiles" BeforeTargets="Publish">
        <ItemGroup>
            <JobFile Include="Settings.job" />
        </ItemGroup>
        <Copy SourceFiles="@(JobFile)" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Nightly' " SkipUnchangedFiles="false" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

This works locally, in that the settings.job file is conditionally copied to the output folder, but the file is not published to Azure. I have tried multiple combinations of BeforeTargets & AfterTargets : Build, Publish, PrepareForPublish all to no avail.

The only way I can get the file to publish out to Azure is if I set it to always copy in the project file:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Update="Settings.job">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

Why does the conditionally copied file not get included in the publish to Azure? Has anyone been able to get this concept working?

Comment: You can take a look of my answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out how to make the conditional publish work. I just moved the condition check to the project file instead of trying to make it happen in the pubxml file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Update="Settings.job" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Nightly'">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Hi Dale, I am glad to hear you found.the solution, you can [mark yourself answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) to end this question, this will be beneficial for others who encounter similar issue and seeking for the solution, Thanks for your sharing! :)

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the `Settings.job` file is conditionally copied to the output folder locally, but it's not being included in the publish process to Azure.

This is the publish file on my side:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121.
-->
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>MSDeploy</WebPublishMethod>
    <PublishProvider>AzureWebSite</PublishProvider>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>https://webjob12xxx11.azurewebsites.net</SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>false</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ResourceId>/subscriptions/8xxx193e/resourcegroups/bowmantest/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/WebJob1202xxx911</ResourceId>
    <UserName>$WebJob12xxx1911</UserName>
    <_SavePWD>true</_SavePWD>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>false</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <MSDeployServiceURL>webjob12xxx911.scm.azurewebsites.net:443</MSDeployServiceURL>
    <MSDeployPublishMethod>WMSVC</MSDeployPublishMethod>
    <SkipExtraFilesOnServer>true</SkipExtraFilesOnServer>
    <EnableMsDeployAppOffline>true</EnableMsDeployAppOffline>
    <EnableMSDeployBackup>true</EnableMSDeployBackup>
    <DeployIisAppPath>WebJob120xxx911</DeployIisAppPath>
    <WebJobType>Triggered</WebJobType>
    <WebJobName>WebJob1</WebJobName>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!-- ... This is the key part ... -->
  <Target Name="IncludeSettingsJob" BeforeTargets="PrepareForPublish">
    <ItemGroup>
      <Content Include="Settings.job">
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
      </Content>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
  <!-- ... This is the key part ... -->

</Project>
```

After publish, the file will be upload to azure successfully:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried the same format you posted and the settings.job file does not get published. In your project is the settings.job file set to copy to the output directory? Mine is set to "Do not copy".

Comment: @DaleLundgren On my side, it if copy always, and it is default setting, I didn't change it. :)

Comment: when it is set to "Copy Always" it will always be published. I need to control if it gets published based on the build configuration. See my posted answer.